# ERROR when attempting to install tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im getting this in tensorflow when I attempt to test my installation with this command.

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

This is the error I get:

```
  File "C:\TensorFlow\models\official\modeling\tf_utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from official.modeling import activations
  File "C:\TensorFlow\models\official\modeling\activations\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from official.modeling.activations.gelu import gelu
  File "C:\TensorFlow\models\official\modeling\activations\gelu.py", line 20, in <module>
    @tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package='Text')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.utils' has no attribute 'register_keras_serializable'
```

I am running tensorflow in a anaconda virtual environment. I am running tensorflow 2.3.0.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a relatively new version of Tensorflow, I think the function 'register_keras_serializable' is already available. With that said, maybe you can try removing the '@' symbol and see if it works.